# How do you call a controller method from an onchange event?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

How do you call a controller method from an onchange event?

I'm using Spring MVC.

I have a `<form:list>` and I wish to update the current page when an onchange event is triggered in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Just submit the form to the server. You can use the inherited `form.submit()` function in JS for this.

```
onchange="submit()"
```

In the server side you can do your conditional thing based on the submitted input values.

As a modern alternative, you can also do this totally transparently by firing an asynchronous HTTP request using JS (also known as Ajax). But since you're using Spring MVC and I don't do Spring MVC, I can't suggest how to properly glue Ajax with Spring MVC. You can at least find some articles at Google, for example [this one](http://www.jtraining.com/blogs/ajax-with-spring-mvc-and-jquery.html).